# Не отображаются расширения в xcode

Tags: xcode, storyboard

Почему-то не отображается расширение файлов при работе со *storyboard* 
Как это можно исправить? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если параметры Xcode не жалко, то можно в терминале их сбросить `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode` и посмотреть поможет ли. А так в настройках View надо копаться. `View → Navigators` / `View → Group → Type`

Comment: @DiMithras сброс к сожалению не помог((